# Reading BMP file gives back unexpected data

Tags: c++, bitmap

I made a bitmap with the following first row:
0000000000000000000000000000000111111111 
(It's a black line on the edge of the bitmap)
But when I read the bitmap I get back the following data on the first row:
1000100100001001000010010000100100001001

Actually the first 3 rows contain the 1's and some zeros. The rest of the values are 0's.
I use the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    FILE* f = fopen("C:\\Users\\Laptop_Chris\\Documents\\kleinObject.bmp", "rb");
    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f);

    int size = ((*(int*)&info[18] * 3 + 3) & (~3)) * *(int*)&info[22]; //BMP - HEIGHT: *(int*)&info[22]  -  WIDTH:*(int*)&info[18]

    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size];
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f);
    fclose(f);

    vector< vector<bool> > myVector;
    myVector.resize(*(int*)&info[22], vector<bool>(*(int*)&info[18]));

    int i = 0;

    for (auto a = 0; a < *(int*)&info[22]; a++) {
        for (auto q = 0; q < *(int*)&info[18]; q++) {
            if ((int(data[i] & 0xFF) + int(data[i + 1] & 0xFF) + int(data[i + 2] & 0xFF)) > 0) {
                myVector[a][q] = false;
            }
            else {
                myVector[a][q] = true;
            }
            i = i + 3;
            cout << myVector[a][q];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Anybody that understands this behavior?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're sticking to C++, why don't you use the `fstream` library instead of the C library for file management? Therefore, you're code can be more readable and easier to program (unless efficiency is really important in your program).

Comment: Instead of raw arrays and typecasting, why not use BITMAPFILEHEADER and BITMAPINFOHEADER structures? For example: [How can I read BMP pixel values into an array?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5751749)

Comment: Since you are making some assumptions (RGB24, biHeight > 0), it is hard to tell what's going on without having your input image. Also note that you are outputting 1 for R=G=B=0 (i.e. black) and 0 otherwise.

Comment: I am not using any libraries because in the end this code had to be used on a linux machine. To be sure everything worked properly this approach was used.

Comment: If you are looking for plain and standalone code for reading/writing of uncompressed bitmap images, running on practically any machine, you might wanna look at the class [CByteImage](http://ivt.sourceforge.net/doxygen/_byte_image_8cpp_source.html) from IVT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are that you have a RGB24 bitmap and that BITMAPINFOHEADER::biHeight > 0 (that is your `*(int*)&info[22]`). Note that this means that your image is stored from bottom row to top row.

Furthermore, you handle 4 byte padding when computing `size`, but you are not handling it when reading out `data`.

Also note that you are outtputting 1 for R=G=B=0 (i.e. black) and 0 otherwise. You probably intend the opposite.

You should also add a `delete [] data;` at the end.

Summary: your code only works for an RGB24 image with biHeight > 0 and (3 * biWidth) % 4 == 0 and you have to be aware that you are outputting from bottom row to top row and 1 for R=G=B=0 and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Yep. That is exactly what it was. Thanks! Marked as answer.